# Readonly fields becomes null when disposing from finalizer

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I've the following class. Now sometimes the lock statement is throwing an `ArgumentNullException`, and in that case I can then see in the debugger that `disposelock` object is really null.

As I can see that disposing is false, I know that the method is triggered from Finalizer.

But how can this happen ? It is defined as readonly and gets its value when the object is created.

PS: I know that this isn't a good pattern, but its part of a given code, and I just can't explain why this becomes null

```
public abstract class DisposableMarshalByRefObject : MarshalByRefObject, IDisposable
{
    private readonly object disposeLock = new object();


   /// </summary>
   ~DisposableMarshalByRefObject()
   {
       Dispose(false);
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Performs application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources.
   /// </summary>
   public void Dispose()
   {
       Dispose(true);
       GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
   }

   protected void Dispose(bool disposing) //disposing = false,=> finalizer
   {
       lock (disposeLock) //ArgumentNull Exception !
       {
           ....
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. This looks specious to me.

Comment: Is there a finalizer? Maybe the object was already disposed and you need to suppress the finializing

Comment: I can't reproduce it in a small program. Primarily i'm wondering wether it is could be a expected behavior that the finalization process could nullify readonly references  prior the finalizer has been completed

Comment: On *garbage collecting* (`~DisposableMarshalByRefObject())` the order of that collection (`this` - first, then -`disposeLock` or `disposeLock` first, then `this`) is *not determined*.

Comment: @ehh in the dispose the suppress is called. I added t he code to the snippet in my post.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko so its a expected behavior that when comming from finalize the readonly field could be null?

Comment: @BoasEnkler: `readonly`, in fact, is a language feature. Runtime doesn't prevent readonly fields from modification. E.g., you can use reflection to set `readonly` field value.

Comment: @Dennis I didn't think at that. from this point of view  it seens to be logical that the disposelock could be removed before or at the moment the code is running

Comment: @Boas Enkler: it's *possible behaviour*: GC can start from any object, so the code can work, say, on my computer and fail on your

Comment: Interesting. In your case, when you come to `Dispose(bool)` _from the finalizer_ (destructor), it should be unnecessary to `lock` since we can assume (I think) that no-one can hold on to the `disposeLock` instance. If someone else held the lock, we would never have started garbage collection in the first place. This "proof" might require that the reference to `disposeLock` is not passed to people outside your class (or otherwise "taken" even if it is `private`)?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen The other object that might trigger the lock might be eligible for garbage collection as well but have a reference to the instance of `DisposableMarshalByRefObject`. If its finalizer triggers a call to a method on `DisposableMarshalByRefObject` on a different thread, the lock would be required.

Comment: 1) Could you insert an assertion with a unique error message to check if `disposeLock` is really and the exception isn't triggered by some other value being null? 2) Do you use remoting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On *garbage collection* the order of that collection is not defined:

1. First `this` is collected
2. Next `disposeLock` is collected

Or

1. First `disposeLock` is collected
2. Next `this` is collected

So do not use any *reference* fields (*structs* like `int`, `bool` etc. are safe) on `Dispose(false);`

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
  if (disposing) {
    // Explicit disposing: it's safe to use disposeLock 
    lock (disposeLock) {
      ...
    }
  } 
  else {
    // Garbage collection: there's no guarantee that disposeLock has not been collected
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? AFAIK having a not yet triggered finalizer resurrects the object and all objects referenced by it. What's not defined is the order in which the finalizers are called. While the order of collection isn't specified, neither object can be collected until after the finalizer has run and you could only observe this undefined order via weak references, which are not shown in the example.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: `disposeLock` doesn't have finalizer, it can't be resurrected, and that's why can be collected

Comment: AFAIK an object with a finalizer temporarily prevents the collection (but not the finalization) of all objects reachable from it. If it permanently resurrects itself, those refereced objects get permanently resurrected themselves.

Comment: When an object is collected its references are not set to null. This does not explain why the field is null. Since the lock is just an `object` the GC does not process it at all until it truly is unreachable.

Comment: I agree with Usr: This answer does not explain how a ArgumentNullException occurs.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is wrong. .NET touts a feature called memory-safety that specifies that your code can never see a 'collected' reference. A referenced object may have been disposed but not collected.

Answer (score 7):

All existing answers except the reflection answer are false. The GC does not set references to null when it collects objects. Object access does not spuriously fail due to the GC. The order of finalization is undefined but all object references that exist continue to exist and are valid.

My guess for what happened: The constructor was aborted before the field was initialized. That left the field `null`. The finalizer then later found it like that.

A constructor can be aborted by throwing an exception, or by calling `Thread.Abort` which is evil.

> On garbage collection the order of that collection is not defined

The order of *collection* is not *observable* (except through weak references...). The order of *finalization* is observable, but not with the `lock` statement because objects do not loose the ability to synchronize when finalized.

Comment: The (dis)prove this explanation, insert a logging call in the constructor (which shows that the object has been constructed completely) and if you get a finializer that throws the null reference exception, check your logs to see if the constructor for it finshed, or not.

Answer (score 4):

Since you've accentuated `readonly`, a little clarification about it. Runtime doesn't prevent `readonly` fields from modification. Regardless of `readonly` from C# becomes `initonly` in IL.

E.g., you can easily modify `readonly` field using reflection:

```
class A
{
    private readonly int bar;

    public A()
    {
        bar = 1;
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(bar);
    }
}

var a = new A();

a.Foo(); // displays "1"
a.GetType().GetField("bar", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(a, 2);
a.Foo(); // displays "2"
```

Of course, this doesn't mean, that you should test these fields for `null` every time, but there *could be* cases, when `readonly` field becomes modified (you've faced one of them).

As a side note. Do you really need finalizer? I mean, are there any *true* unmanaged resources?